# CMake Zero Check fails to detect updates in CMakeLists.txt files for Xcode generator

Tags: c++, xcode, cmake

### Background

I have big project which builds runs on windows perfectly.
When some changes are applied in `CMakeLists.txt` and project is build, Visual Studio project is properly updated.

Xcode version: 10.0 (10A255) or 10.1 (10B61) (tested on different machines).

CMake version: 3.12.2 or 3.13.1

### Problem

Problem appears when same project is build on Mac OS for Xcode.
After configuring CMake:

```
cmake .. -G Xcode
```

Generated project works fine, everything builds properly and test are passing.

Now when `CMakeLists.txt` files are modified (when developing project or when fetching new changes from repository) and `ZERO_CHECK` or `BUILD_ALL` are selected, build doesn't lead to Xcode project update.
Invoking `cmake .` doesn't detect changes too.

### Workaround

The best workaround I've found is deleting <del>everything</del> two files: `cmake_install.cmake` and `CMakeCache.txt`. Then rerun command which generates project `cmake .. -G Xcode`.
In this scenario whole detection is redone from scratch, but at least build doesn't start from zero (unchanged files are not recompiled).

This is painful, since lots of manual stuff must be done, and project have to be recreated and this consumes time.

### Hints

In some previous project I had similar problem, but it was happening only if maven was detecting updates for dependencies, so it happened quite rarely. When it happened I just called `touch CMakeLists.txt` and build again and this workaround was fine. This solution doesn't applies since every build has this issue.

I was suspecting that protobuf generation procedure has something with it, but when I've disabled it problem still persists.

I've tried to provide complete minimal example, by creating simple project file, but I was not able to reproduce the issue. For all other projects it just works, so system configuration is not the issue.

### Questions

How can I debug project generation process when running `cmake` to find source of this problem?

Is this a known problem?

Is there a better workaround which will not lead <del>to full rebuild</del> regenerating project file (which also involves detecting system capabilities)?

Comment: This is odd, I never had issues on this. Almost each time I change a CMakeLists.txt in my project, I get a "Canceled" state. Sometimes, it even gets to "Failed", and then I use the GUI to generate the project and it rebuilds the project as I expect.

Comment: May this issue is related https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/14297 ? What version of cmake do you use?

Comment: @user1244932 interesting, but this is not that. First of all my other CMake projects are working fine in any scenario and this project doesn't work even if I select "ALL_BUILD".

Comment: @MarekR can you provide your CMake and XCode versions?

Comment: @Antwane: question updated.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this a known problem?

Over on the CMake Discourse, Craig Scott (one of the CMake maintainers) has commented on a variant of this bug as a known architectural limitation of Xcode:

> With the Xcode generator, targets have a dependency on the `ZERO_CHECK` target, which is what re-runs `cmake` for you automatically if something changed. But the problem is that the rest of the build in that run still uses the old details from before `cmake .` gets run. If you build again, that rebuilds anything whose details changed, but explicitly re-running `cmake .` first if you know something about the project changed will be more robust and probably avoid more unnecessary rebuilds.

-- https://discourse.cmake.org/t/documented-criteria-for-build-correctness/3087/2?u=alex

Your comment that "invoking `cmake .` doesn't detect changes" is strange in light of this, but it could be that old CMake versions, like 3.12 and 3.13 which you were using when this question was asked, had a bug that has since been fixed. It could also be something project-specific that we can only guess at. Missing a `CMAKE_CONFIGURE_DEPENDS` directory property? Have a bad `set(... CACHE ... FORCE)` call? Can't say...